# Conjugacy Classes in the Free Group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $F_n$ be the free group on $n$ generators, and let $u$ and $v$ be two of $F_n$'s generators. My question is,

> Do there exist $a, b \in F_n$ such that $(u^{-1}v)^{-1} = b^{-1}a u^{-1}v a^{-1} b$?

Comment: Weird question: why do you want to know? Where does this come from? What the mixed conjugating elements $\;g_1,g_2\;$ ?

Comment: @us  Ok...but I think you messed up the indexes in the left side of your rightmost expression: should it perhaps be $\;g_2^{-1}\color{red}{g_1}u^{-1}vg_1^{-1}g_2\;?$ . This is another reason why, if possible, it is worthwhile to choose letter without indexes, say $\;a,b\;$ or something.

Comment: @DonAntonio Whoops. I believe it is fixed, now.

Comment: @us I'm afraid you forgot now to include $\;u\;$ somewhere there...

Comment: In general it is is easy to decide whether two elements of a free group are conjugate. They are conjugate if and only if their cyclic reductions are equivalent under a cyclic permutation of their letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.  You can see this very quickly by considering the map $\varphi:F_n\to\mathbb{Z}^n$ sending the generators of $F_n$ to the coordinate vectors (this is the abelianization of $F_n$).  Since $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is abelian, $\varphi(b^{-1}au^{-1}va^{-1}b)=\varphi(u^{-1}v)$.  But $\varphi(u^{-1}v)\neq \varphi((u^{-1}v)^{-1}))$, since $\varphi(u^{-1}v)\neq 0$ and no nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is its own inverse.

Comment: ...Of course! I should have known to abelianize! This is rather embarrassing...Thanks!